# How to change label value by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

My ASP.NET page includes:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblDoc" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
```

I want to change the value by using javascript / jquery.

```
$("#<%=lblDoc.ClientID%>").val("Hello World");
```

but it doesn't work? Have you got any idea? Is it wrong?

Comment: I don't know ASP.NET, but just looking at it, I think it should be: `$("#lblDoc").text("Hello World");` The [`$.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is for setting a `value` on an element that supports `value` attributes, [`$.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and [`$.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) are for altering the inner text and inner html, respectively.

Comment: Note, `$("#<%=lblDoc.ClientID%>").text("Hello World!!!");` or `$("#<%=lblDoc.ClientID%>").html("Hello World!!!");` seems to be correct.

Comment: yeag, it works Jared Farrish, thanx..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.val()` changes the "value" for form input elements. Instead, to change the actual content of an element, use `.text("Hello World")` for plain text, or `.html("<span>Hello World</span>")` for HTML.